# Python loop equation calculation

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops, math

I'm trying to create a function which outputs an array of calculated values, the first function is fine, however, its the second I am having difficulty with, the first being:

```
def f(x):
    x * 2
```

the second function I think should look something like this, but I am not getting anything,

```
def genSample(x):
sample = []


for i in range(x):
    y  = f(x)
    
    z = sample.append(y)

print(z)
```

here I am trying to use x = 100, and have it calculate each new value using f(x), save these new values to the array samples and then return samples at the end when all values up to 100 have been calculated. There is clearly an error somewhere, since I'm not getting any values outputted, but I'm a bit unsure.

Comment: You need to have your first function return a value: `return x * 2`. Then you also don't need to use `z`, just go `sample.append(y) -> print(sample)`

Comment: Thanks thats worked! Suppose you can help me with now setting x to be a random number between 0 and 10 and have 100 values of them? At the moment, I've tried randomlist = random.sample(range(0, 10), 100) . But I get an error saying sample larger than population.